# Reattaching to a container that was started with kubectl exec -it <pod> -- bash

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to reconnect  to a container that was started with `kubectl exec -it <pod> -- bash`

The terminal connection broke and I would like to get back into the same session. Is it possible to re-attach?

If I do another kubectl exec and grep for process, I see the process is still running

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31824/how-do-i-attach-a-terminal-to-a-detached-process

Comment: The question is a bit incorrect. `kubectl exec` does not start a container. In your case it attaches a new bash shell to already existing container process. So you want to return to that exact shell, right? Why, what for?